# Only first elseif in if/elseif/else statement is working

Tags: php

Only the `elseif (isset($foo['read']))` on line 37 is working, the `if` and first `elseif` work, when I try to call the second `elseif`, it returns the first `elseif` statements output. I have even swapped the two `elseif` statements and it still only returned the first `elseif` statement output when calling the second `elseif` statement.

```
<?php

$nh = "true";
$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");
//$stuff = json_decode($foo, true);


function savetxt($sttext)
{
    $filename = 'test.txt';
    $somecontent = $sttext;

    if (is_writable($filename)) { 
        if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
             echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
             exit;
        }
        if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
            echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
            exit;
        }

        echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

        fclose($handle);

    }
    else {
        echo "The file $filename is not writable";
    }
}

if (strpos($foo, 'write:') !== false) {
    echo 'Attempting to write!';
    $stext = substr($foo, 6);
    savetxt($stext); 
} 
elseif ($foo == "read"){
    echo file_get_contents( "test.txt" );
} 
elseif ($foo == "test){
    echo 'Working!';
} 
else {
    echo 'Didn't get test.';
}
?>
```

Comment: This isn't a `syntax-error`.

Comment: So? Sorry kinda new to PHP.

Comment: little confused by your description but are you expecting it to go into each of the if/else when it matches the condition ? When you say "when I try to call the second elseif, it returns the first elseif statements output"  it sounds like it is working as expected  if the condition for the first elseif is matched, it is not going to attempt any of the other elseif conditions.  If you wanted all conditions to always be checked, use a bunch of if statements, not elseif

Comment: It shouldn't match the first though, I am sending the string "test" not "read" but I am getting "read"s output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this(you must replace else if with elseif)

```
else if ($foo && $foo=='read')
```

and

```
else if ($foo && $foo=='test')
```

and at end

```
else if (!$foo || $foo=='')
```